# Get the memory usage, CPU usage, disk usage in windows 10 UWP C#

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-runtime, windows-10

I have windows 10 UWP app and I want to write information (memory usage, CPU usage, disk usage) in a file of this app when it is running in foreground or background.

So, how to get the memory usage, CPU usage, disk usage in windows 10 UWP in C#?

Comment: [UWP app diagnostics](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/06/28/uwp-app-diagnostics/) looks like what you're looking for.

Comment: Hi @RaymondChen, I checked that one and I think it is collecting information of other apps looping on each running apps.

Comment: It wasn't clear whether you wanted all apps or just your own app. The article also tells you how to get the diagnostic info for just the current app.

Comment: I want to get information of my app from my app itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the `MemoryManager` class, it provides access to information on an app's memory usage. And we can use `ProcessDiagnosticInfo.CpuUsage` and `ProcessDiagnosticInfo.DiskUsage` to get CPU usage, disk usage in current process.

[**ProcessCpuUsage**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.diagnostics.processcpuusage.aspx) class has no constructor, it provides access to data about the CPU usage of a process. And this class only has a [**GetReport**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.diagnostics.processcpuusage.getreport.aspx) method, which gets the [**ProcessCpuUsageReport**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.diagnostics.processcpuusagereport.aspx) for the process. With `ProcessCpuUsageReport` class, we can get [**KernelTime**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.diagnostics.processcpuusagereport.kerneltime) and [**UserTime**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.diagnostics.processcpuusagereport.usertime) consumed by the process.

To get a `ProcessCpuUsage` object, we need use [**ProcessDiagnosticInfo.CpuUsage**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.diagnostics.processdiagnosticinfo.cpuusage.aspx) property. This is one of the properties in [**ProcessDiagnosticInfo**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.diagnostics.processdiagnosticinfo.aspx) class. This class provides diagnostic information about a process, such as CPU usage, disk usage, memory usage and so on. And `ProcessDiagnosticInfo` class has two static methods: [**GetForCurrentProcess**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.diagnostics.processdiagnosticinfo.getforcurrentprocess.aspx) and [**GetForProcesses**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.diagnostics.processdiagnosticinfo.getforprocesses.aspx) that help us to get the `ProcessDiagnosticInfo`.

However, please note that these two methods can only get the ProcessDiagnosticInfo related to your own app. GetForProcesses method can return a list of `ProcessDiagnosticInfo` objects for all running processes. But here the "all running processes" means all running processes in the same App Container.